# Django form filter not selecting output

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

My form shows all the ce_hostname objects in the database with a dropdown. I want to filter the ce_hostname to ones which only have a common order reference. I can't get this working. My dropdown is currently blank.

forms.py

```
class Cx_BaseForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
                model = Cx_Base
                fields = ['cx_hostname', 'new', 'ce_hostname', 'location', 'manged_module_model', 'slot']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(Cx_BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['ce_hostname'].queryset = Ce_Base.objects.filter(order_reference=self.instance.order_reference)
```

models.py

```
class Ce_Base(models.Model):
    ce_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[CE_HOSTNAME_REGEX], verbose_name="CE Hostname", help_text="Hostname of router.")
    order_reference = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cx_Base(models.Model):

    order_reference = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                     
    cx_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[CX_HOSTNAME_REGEX], verbose_name="CX Hostname", help_text="Hostname of Switch.")                                  
    new = models.BooleanField(help_text="Select if installing new hardware. Leave blank if switch exists on DCN.")                                                                                              
    ce_hostname = models.ForeignKey(Ce_Base, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="CE Hostname", help_text="Hostname of router in which the module will be inserted.")                                     
    location = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, help_text="Address of site. Leave blank if not new.")
    manged_module_model = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=MANAGED_MODULES, help_text="Hardware model of switch. Leave blank if not new.")               
    slot = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, choices=SLOT, help_text="Slot in which the module will be inserted. Leave blank if not new.")                                               

    l2_interfaces = JSONField(null=True)                                                                               

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cx_hostname
```

Edit:

Here is the views.py. I assume what I need to do is somehow pass in pk_test when the instance of the form cx_base_form is created, then I can use it the same way that I do in the views.

If I hard code this it works.

```
self.fields['ce_hostname'].queryset = Ce_Base.objects.filter(order_reference='1')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def addCX_Base(request, pk_test):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm()
    cx_base_form.instance.order_reference = order
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm(request.POST)
        cx_base_form.instance.order_reference = order
        if request.POST.get("new") == "on":
            print(request.POST.get("new"))
        else:
            for managed_module in inventory["managed_modules"]:
                print(managed_module["model"])
                model = request.POST.get("manged_module_model")
                print(model)
                if model == managed_module["model"]:
                    print(managed_module["l2_ports"])
                    cx_base_form.instance.l2_interfaces = managed_module["l2_ports"]
            if cx_base_form.is_valid():
                cx_base_form.save()
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                print("Form is not valid")

    context = {'cx_base_form':cx_base_form}
    return render(request, 'orchestration/cx_base_form.html', context)
```

Comment: Is this in the admin? Can you share some sample data that you used?

Comment: Hello, I have edited to include my views.py. I assume this is what you need.

Comment: In this line `cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm(request.POST)`, you aren't passing any instance to the form, so in your custom field queryset, `self.instance.order_reference` is `None`. It seems you intended to use `cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm(request.POST, instance=cx_base_form.instance)`?

Comment: In the top 2 lines of the class, cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm()- this is the thing which creates an instance of the class isn't it? The post stuff later on is just to get the values from the form when the submit button is hit. i.e. ignore all that stuff after the IF.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now. You will have to pass `order` in a different way, maybe as part of `__init__`. I'll add an answer you can try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is created with `Cx_BaseForm()`, the form will have an instance of the model that has no values (related code [`here`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#L357-L360)). This then means `self.instance.order_reference` on the `__init__` method would be `None`, causing the issue you have observed.

If you want to pass the `order` from the view to the form, one approach is pass the `order` to the form like this:

```py
@login_required
def addCX_Base(request, pk_test):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk_test)
    cx_base_form = Cx_BaseForm(order_reference=order) # pass it to the form
    if request.method == 'POST':
    # ...
```

No need to do `cx_base_form.instance.order_reference = order`. Then add the handling for `order_reference` on the form:

```py
class Cx_BaseForm(ModelForm):
    # ...
    def __init__(self, *args, order_reference=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if order_reference:
            self.fields['ce_hostname'].queryset = Ce_Base.objects.filter(
                order_reference=order_reference,
            )
```